# Conditional Page Break On XtraReports Table

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a grid on my XtraReports and i would like to place in a conditional page break my list consist of oranges, Lemons and Apples and their descriptions. how do i iterate through each row and get a Field value for particular column.

i have tried accessing the detail Report which is my grid table name and Get Current Column Value but that is not what i am looking for because row 1 will have apple and row 2 will have lemons so i want to break each time when row 1 column 1 does not match row 2 column 1

```
    private void xrPageBreak1_BeforePrint_1(object sender, 
     System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        SetBreaks(sender);
    }


    private void SetBreaks(object sender)
    {
        XRPageBreak control = sender as XRPageBreak;

     var ItemName = 
     DetailReport.GetCurrentColumnValue("Item").ToString();
     if(ItemName == "Apple")
        {
         control.Visible = true;
        }


    }
```

the code above returns "Apple"